# How can I prevent user from displaying content of the shiro.ini file in Zeppelin

Tags: shiro, apache-zeppelin

I followed the turorial from [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-zeppelin-on-ubuntu-16-04) on how to install and use Zeppelin. I also created users with passwords by specifying them in the `conf/shiro.ini` file.

The problem however is that a user can write this simple script to see the contents of the shiro file.

```
%python
import os
os.system("cat <path_to_zeppelin_folder>conf/shiro.ini")
```

My question is, how can I prevent the user from seeing this file, as this file is accessed by the Zeppelin program and therefore I can't just make it unreadable by removing read permissions.

What I am doing now is to remove read/write permissions of the `shiro.ini` file after starting Zeppelin, but there should be a more elegant way of preventing such a thing.

Comment: Just set the permissions to 700 and activate 'User Impersonate' for all your interpreters.

Comment: User impersonation doesn't work for the Spark interpreter. It does work for the livy.spark interpreter but livy.spark doesn't support the z variable.

Comment: With Zrppelin 0.8 you can store password hashs in shiro.ini. Have a look at: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/229953/how-to-create-securely-hashed-passwords-for-local.html